# Passing a JSP value to a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, jsp

I have this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var data=$('#data').val();
    var counter = 1;
    var d=new Date();
    var i;
    var newdate= new Array();
    newdate=$('#newdate').val();
   newdate= newdate.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
   var newdate1=newdate.split(",");
    var a=newdate1[0];
    var b=newdate1[1];
    var c=newdate1[2];
    var dateString=$('#strtime').val();
    var dateString2=$('#endtime').val();
    var dateString1=$('#date').val();

    var d1 = new Date(dateString1+" "+dateString);
    var d5= new Date(dateString1+" "+dateString2);
    alert(d5);
    var yo=d1;
    var d3=new Date(dateString1+" "+a);
    var d4=new Date(dateString1+" "+b);
    setInterval(function() {
    if(yo.getTime() <= d.getTime()){//compare current time and add half n hour to the db time variable and create a new textbox  
    if(yo.getTime() <= d5.getTime()){
        //alert("hello");
    if( (d1.getTime() == d3.getTime()) || (d1.getTime() == d4.getTime())){
    var freq=$('#freq').val();
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

//the problem lies here
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div><textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="data'+data+'"/>');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    yo.setMinutes(yo.getMinutes() + 30);
        }
    }
    },1000);
 });
</script>

html code
<input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="<%=rsta.getString("data");%>"/>
```

The script adds text box depending on time, in this case every half an hour.

I take some data from the db, pass it to a hidden field,and take the value in the script.
I used alert in the script to display the data from the database and it displays too.
But when I pass it to the value field in this line of code

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo
                           +'</label></div><textarea name="textbox' + counter 
                           + '" id="textbox' + counter 
                           + '" value=""/>');
```

the data doesn't appear. Am I doing something wrong?
Even if I hard code and write something in the value it doesn't display.
I also tried passing using JSP directly but that too doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div>
     <textarea name="textbox'+ counter  +'" id="textbox'+counter+ '">
      data'+data+'</textarea>');
```

Comment: also I forgot to mention the freq variable I am not able to pass inside.I want to pass it instead of 30.But it doesnt work.

Comment: try using `parseInt(freq)`;

Comment: ok i will try..but can i use it in javascript? i dont think so..will have to use jsp i guess

Comment: you just want to pass the sum of `freq` and `yo.getMinutes()` right, `parseInt(freq)` will convert the `freq` value(string) to integer then the addition can happen.

Comment: how to pass it using jsp?do u have any idea?`<textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" >'<%=data%>'</textarea>');`isnt this correct?because when I say system.out data,i get the value in the console.

Comment: try this `'<textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" ><%=data%></textarea>'` but I suppose you will have to submit the form once

Comment: I tried this.But doesnt work.the textboxes dont appear at all,leave alone the data in the textboxes.

Comment: probably because you are not having the _data_ , you will have to submit the form or try using ajax to get the _data_ from the server side

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of this:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
```

try with this:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div/>').attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
newTextBoxDiv.after('<div><label style="float:left;">...all other code');
```

So to me this code should be like this:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div/>').attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

//the problem lies here
newTextBoxDiv.after('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo
                    +'</label></div><textarea name="textbox' + counter 
                    + '" id="textbox' + counter 
                    + '">data'+data+'"</textarea>'); //<---see this here
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
yo.setMinutes(yo.getMinutes() + 30);
```

and even you don't have to call `.html()` you can pass all your html in `.after()` method this will push your html after your target element.

[documentation @jQuery for .after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

**Description**: *Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.*

Comment: now it seems your problem lies here:  `+ '">data'+data+'"</textarea>');`

Comment: do u know jsp by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

try something  like this

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div><textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" >data'+data+'</textarea>');
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the "data" that you are getting, When I hard code and put an alert to 
`'<div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div>
     <textarea name="textbox'+ counter  +'" id="textbox'+counter+ '">
      data'+data+'</textarea>'`
I get what I put in. So it most probably something to do with data.

Also can you just put a debug alert inside your "if" conditions and see if your are reaching the code that has the error.